# Set state function on a key/value (shared_preferences) doesn't work for displaying the new value

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building a little pomodoro app with Flutter. I'm using the package shared_preferences to store a String and a Int.

Everything is working fine (loading and saving), but I'm trying to automatically change the displaying of the Int value with SetState, which doesn't work. The displaying value only change when I reload the app.

My saving method is :

```
_savePomo() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
  prefs.setInt('pomodoro', pomodoro);
});
}
```

The method is called everytime the podomoro finish a cycle. Before calling the method I increment the pomodoro variable =+1.
I'm showing the value like this :

```
Text("It's your " + _pomodoro.toString() +"th pomodoro !");
```

Everything is happening in a stateful widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code:-

```
int pomodoro = 0;
_savePomo() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setInt('pomodoro', pomodoro);
    pomodoro = await prefs.getInt('pomodoro');
}
```

You can use pomodoro variable in Text widget like below:-

```
Text("It's your " + pomodoro.toString() +"th pomodoro !");
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you do this:

```
_pomodoro += 1;
```

Convert it into this:

```
setState(() {
  _pomodoro += 1;
});
```

You also do not need to place the `prefs.setInt` in `setState`.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer: I have a variable 'laps' that increment =+1 in a set state method, then I add the laps variable to the pomodoro key_value this way : _sauverPomo() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      int pomodoro = (prefs.getInt('pomodoro') ?? 0);
      pomodoro = pomodoro + laps;
      prefs.setInt('pomodoro', pomodoro);
    });
  }